# How can I group a list if have same value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dict like this

```
[
{'id':1,'product_id':20,'price':50,'quantity':1, 'name':'product_2'},
{'id':2,'product_id':20,'price':50,'quantity':1, 'name':'product_2'},
{'id':3,'product_id':30,'price':20,'quantity':4, 'name':'product_3'},
]
```

how can i group this list and get result like this

```
[
{'id':1,'product_id':20,'price':100,'quantity':2, 'name':'product_2'},
{'id':3,'product_id':30,'price':20,'quantity':4, 'name':'product_3'},
]
```

thanks ♥

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for doing your homework for you.

Comment: lol it not homework.im leaning how to code and i just stuck and need some hint 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group the dictionaries based on a common key (e.g. product_id).  This can be done by converting the list of dictionaries into a dictionary of dictionaries.  You then combine the additive keys in each unique instance of dictionaries in the groups.

```
aList= [
{'id':1,'product_id':20,'price':50,'quantity':1, 'name':'product_2'},
{'id':2,'product_id':20,'price':50,'quantity':1, 'name':'product_2'},
{'id':3,'product_id':30,'price':20,'quantity':4, 'name':'product_3'},
]

groups = dict()  # product_id:dictionary 
for d in aList:
    group = groups.setdefault(d["product_id"],d) # add/get first occurrence
    if group is not d: 
        group["price"]    += d["price"]    # combine additive fields
        group["quantity"] += d["quantity"] # for duplicates
        
aList = list(groups.values()) # convert groups back to a list

print(aList)

[{'id': 1, 'product_id': 20, 'price': 100, 'quantity': 2, 'name': 'product_2'}, 
 {'id': 3, 'product_id': 30, 'price': 20, 'quantity': 4, 'name': 'product_3'}]
```